# I'm confused, what is the TRUE way to build an MVC or MVVM design pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mvvm

So I've been looking up more tutorials and articles about the MVC design pattern to deepen my understanding of them and I'm starting to doubt if I have been doing it all wrong. So yeah the goal of those patterns are to make code reusable and to minimize repeated code, correct?

I've been seeing various ways of how those design patterns are explained which are confusing me a bit. In the past I thought it was the controller-as-a-mediator-between-model-and-view way, but now I'm learning that that was wrong and that the view is actually much more than just a template. Then I also read somewhere (I think here) that in a true MVC pattern, there is by definition only one model and all the other "models" are just different facets of the single model. Is this the case? Is this the best way to separate code and make it reusable? How would that look like in code? And again somewhere else I read that for web-applications it is better to stick to the MVVM pattern.

So now I'm a bit confused. What IS the most effective pattern to separate concerns in a web-application and make the code reusable? I would prefer to not only see a description of this pattern, but also a short example in code so I understand it better.

Comment: Design patterns are very abastract things that should serve as a mental framework to solve problems, not as the tools of the trade themselves. And discussing MVC in such terms is sure to lock you into a semantic labirynth.

Comment: The answers to this question will contain too many opinions and just a few facts. Asking what framework is better for web apps, is like asking what variable type is better to store currency... It depends of your needs and how you're going to make use of its features.

Comment: @AlanChavez while its partially correct... there are also de-facto standarts (like PSR-0) and principles, like SOLID

Comment: @DaveJust: Oh come on PSR-0 *could* be total crap. So what do you have of a de-facto standard then? An approval of the self-mockery of those using it? So it's hard to turn that into an argument I'd say.

Comment: Maybe my [second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418880/what-design-pattern-would-be-suited-for-a-webapp-where-one-page-consists-of-many) helps to clear things up

Comment: @hakre I would **love** your **citation** or **real and proven facts** on "PSR-0 could be total crap".

Comment: @DaveJust: Well *could* is subject to point of view, but there are some commons (standards) you can not express with PSR-0 albeit it was send out to the world to solve commons. I don't say personally it's total crap, but I would be careful with "de-facto standards" and the weight of them. Sometimes it's because they are actually pretty well reflecting the needs, sometimes it's just in the lack of anything else.

Answer (score 6):

> So yeah the goal of those patterns are to make code reusable and to minimize repeated code, correct?

> Is this the best way to separate code and make it reusable?

Nope. It really isn't.

The goal in MVC and MVC-inspired patterns is to isolate business logic (model layer) from the user interface. And within the UI - to divide it into managing input and output.

Basically, MVC and MVC-inspired patterns are arcitectural design patterns that implement principle know as [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

> Then I also read somewhere (I think here) that in a true MVC pattern, there is by definition only one model and all the other "models" are just different facets of the single model. Is this the case?

No. Model is not a "thing" (class, object). It is a [layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_(object-oriented_design)). Same way as you could say that all of controllers and views are contained in presentation layer or UI layer.

What people refer to as "models" are usually either [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) or (much worse case) some form of [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) implementation.

> And again somewhere else I read that for web-applications it is better to stick to the MVVM pattern.

MVVM pattern add another layer between views and the model layer. It's best used for situations, when you either cannot controller the implementation of the views or/and the model layer.

Most of people confuse it with use of [presentation object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) *(M.Fowler has this nasty habit of adding "model" to everything, which create boundless confusions)* concept. Presentation objects are meant to isolate reusable parts of UI logic.

> How would that look like in code?

MVC and MVC-inspired patterns are created to manage large codebases. You apply MVC patter when simple use of object oriented practices are not enough to make code understandable. You do it by adding additional **constraints** to your codebase. MVC does not add anything new to your application. Instead it restricts where and what code can be written.

And "sort code example" will not actually illustrate the pattern. To actually understand, how it works, you should read something like [PoEAA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) book .. or something similar.

> What IS the most effective pattern to separate concerns in a web-application and make the code reusable?

It's a matter of opinion.

Comment: It's a common courtesy to explain the downvote in the comments.

Comment: Your comments about MVC being created for large codebases does not necessarily translate to them only be useful in such situations.  MVC / MVVM provides a structure that is beneficial regardless of project size.  Often in cases where it seems excessive, you end up revisiting the code at some point and it would have been less effort to just build it that way initially.

Answer (score 4):

> What IS the most effective pattern to separate concerns in a
>   web-application and make the code reusable?

There are no proven patterns for this. When you think of this you probably want to reduce code duplication (*especially in Views*) and make your code readable `&&` maintable as much as possible.

It's a matter of [data abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29)

In fact, by its definition, it directs you in the right way of thinking about things like that.

> I would prefer to not only see a description of this pattern, but also
>   a short example in code so I understand it better.

First of all - Inheritance is the way to go, until it satisfies both, the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

As mentioned above, there's no proven pattern for that, but there's a proven technique for that.

In PHP world, your `MVC/MVVM` application must implement at least:

- PSR-0 Autoloader
- Router + Dispatcher (kinda [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern))

Common things to keep in mind:

### 1. Model is an abstraction layer (in MVC/MVVM/MVP)

That consist of lots classes, that deal with application core logic. 
If you call an object `Model` then you end up violating the [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

#### Wrong implementation:

Let's *imagine* for a moment, that model is a class,

Since in most cases we deal with forms, we basically want:

- Forms to be valid
- `Insert/Update/..` a record if valid, then

So, a "model" for this would look like this:

```
$model = new RegisterForm(...);

if ($model->isFormValid($formData)) {

   if ($model->insertRecord($formData)) {
      echo 'Thanks for registration';
   }
}
```

Which obviously breaks the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). And maybe the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if you inherit from.

#### Correct implementation:

Since model is a layer, then it should look like:

A folder structure **of a model layer** would be similar to

```
/User/Login
  - FormValidator.php
  - FormValidatorInterface.php
  - RecordManager.php
```

And since then, the usage itself is:

```
$formValidator = new User_Login_FormValidator(...);

if ($formValidator->isValid(..form data..)) {

   $recordManager = new User_Login_RecordManager($pdo);

   if ($recordManager->insert(..form data..)) {
      echo 'Logged in';
   }

} else {

   print_r($formValidator->getErrors());
}
```

Now let's break it down ,

When your models are layers:

- You can take advantage over [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), [SOLID Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), which is good for unit-testings.
- Your code becomes easy to read and maintain

When your models are objects, like `FooModel`:

- You're doing it wrong - you mixing a concept with an implementation
- You end up violating both the SRP and the LSP

### 2. What is actually MVC?

As you know it consists of 3 components, but instead of a lecture on this, let's take a look

- Model is an abstraction layer that contains core logic of an application
- A view is a class that directly reads data from a Model and handles user presentation logic.

  > > <sub>Say, if on a login page a user isn't logged in, (that info comes from a Model), you have to show en error, otherwise do a redirect - that's a handling of UI logic</sub>
- A controller **only** (**also known as Editor**) assign variables to a model (that come from `$_POST` or `$_GET`, or to a view

  > > <sub>And keep in mind, that data validation should never be done in controllers. You have to define it in a model, then call it from a view</sub>

### And also note,

You should never `echo/print` anything from classes. **Never!** This should be done outside of the triad, like this,

```
$modelLayer = new ModelLayer(...);

$view = new View($modelLayer, $controller);

$controller = Controller($modelLayer);
$controller->indexAction($_POST[...])

echo $view->render(); // render() should `include()` and capture (via ob_* functions) a HTML template.
```

### 3. What is not MVC?

Here's a collection of wrong ideas, you should keep in mind as well, you will be encountering over and over again:

- A model - its an `$instance` that implement some kind of ActiveRecord or ORM, or abstract table access.
- A view is a dumb HTML template
- A controller is a bridge between models and views, that collect information from a model then passes it to view. It also does data validation and show errors.

The "common workflow" as

```
<?php

$model = new Model();
$view = new View();
$controller = new Controller($model, $view);

$controller->indexAction();
```

### 4. How about MVVM?

Here's a [good article for you](http://r.je/evolving-mvc-into-mvvm.html), that explains it. Note, he names a class `Model` just for demonstration.

Comment: model layer is not a class, and that directory structure makes no sense

Comment: @tereško please read an answer again, esp part 2. I told that a model is not a class

Comment: 1. Since `Authorization` is a typical component, how its very basic usage should be demonstrated then? It must have a folder with its required classes. And you're saying that makes no sense... 2. And again - yes `$modelLayer` is not a class, as mentioned several times above. Do you suggest to a write a lecture on services and how interaction should be done via factories? ..... Therefore `$modelLayer` should be self-understandable

Comment: Did you mean "authentication"? Because authorization checks should be performed outside of the MVC-like structures. An what is the context of first two snippets of code? What sort of files are they supposed to be in? Are you implying that model layer is aware that there is a form or that controllers know about PDO instance?

Comment: @tereško `FormValidator` is not something that looks like `Zend_Form`. It doesn't `print/echo` HTML tags. It has a logic to validate the `length/email/username/password ...` and maybe to translate error messages (if optional `$translator` is injected). The values that come from `$request` are injected into it. And yes, **a model is completely unaware of views and controllers** as demonstrated above. Since `form data validator` and CRUD operations are parts of a singular component, then they do belong to the same layer, otherwise it breaks the `POLS`. That was a point, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

**Going through open source code is the best way to learn**

This question is one that would have a long answer and most probably cause debates since it seems you are asking for an opinion. The best answer in this case to the most "effective pattern" is the pattern that solves your problem.

"Your design should be specific to the problem at hand but also general enough to address future problems and requirements" - GoF (Design Patterns - Elements of reusable objects)

As you say, some say use MVVM (which I haven't heard off) and some of us use the MVC architecture. If you know both, use the one specific to your problem else use any that will work for you.

The best way to learn the MVC architecture and other patterns is not only through theory, but through coding. Take some of the code you have written and try to find where you used some of these patterns without knowing (eg. You might have used the Facade). How I learned and continue to learn is by going through open source code and trying to organise my code in a similar way.

If you are looking for a way to know where exactly to place a file, I don't think you find it. The best that you can do is have a rough idea of how files should be organized. To learn the MVC, download [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and check out how the files are organized whilst having a look at their documentation. Also checkout other opensource code frameworks such [cakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). Etc. I think this is the best way to get a clear understanding of it.

I think your problem is that you have been reading too much and not trying to implement some of the stuff you read.

As for code examples, I think you should google that as "short" is something it won't be. You need too see actual code and not examples. I'm sure you have seen enough examples by now from the tutorials you've been through.

**Edit:**

And notice I used "architecture" instead of "pattern", that's what I was taught. :) But I don't think it's a big deal though. #just-an-opinion

Comment: unless you're talking to a purist, most developers will overlook the fact that you said "architecture" instead of "pattern, unless of course, your job is to know what the difference of each is.

Comment: -1: please don't tell people to "learn from codeigniter and cakephp". Those two are objectively the worst frameworks in PHP.

Comment: @tereško See, the debate thing I mentioned in the second line. My idea is learn from whatever you can get your hands on (first line). Some people like codeigniter and some like zend. Everyone has their reasons. Just start somewhere...

Comment: @tereško while I agree that CI or CakePHP are not necessarily the best MVC Frameworks out there (zend and symfony are way better in almost any sense), they're a good starting point. The learning curve is so low that almost anybody can start writing maintainable code right off the bat, plus you can deploy a project in a shared environment without a hassle. With Zend or Symfony you really have to have a VPS server to have access to all of its resources.

Comment: @AlanChavez if you deem X and Y to be "not necessarily the best" why push a user to learn by them when there are better options available? Surely learning the best methods and approach from the start is less confusing in the long run, no matter how more difficult the better ones are? (not including *equally as good* "easier" options, obviously). `mysql_` is slightly easier to learn than `mysqli` as there is no *object* learning curve (however tiny it may be). Would you advise someone learn `mysql_` first as an introduction, as it's easier...?

Comment: @James because there's no advantage of using `mysql_` over `mysqli`. For starters, `mysql_` is deprecated. In small projects is just an overkill to use Symfony/Zend, Doctrine and Twig alone add a 10MB footprint to the project, besides what if he doesn't have the budget for a VPS? What if he isn't a sysadmin? What if he is not comfortable using a CLI? There are advantages of using CI/CakePHP over Symfony/Zend, one is the learning curve for a total beginner is way lower.

Comment: @AlanChavez But you *are* effectively saying "learn `mysql_` before `mysqli` by advising to learn frameworks that have poor structure and pointless OOP classes. In some cases this logic applies - learn to drive a car before a truck - but in coding (usually), however harder one option is over another to learn, one should learn the harder option IF it's accurate and has better coding standards. Or you're simply learning poor code to then later have to forget a lot of what you learned and re-learn a different way. To quote you: "CI or CakePHP are not necessarily the best MVC Frameworks"..

Comment: @James You're taking my comment out of context by not quoting it in its entirety, I also said that such frameworks are good starting points. At least by using such frameworks, he (and other devs) will  get an understanding of what the separation of concerns means, and I think that's more important than "which framework interprets MVC better". Also, Symfony is not even an MVC Framework, it is a full stack framework.

Comment: Also, I think that trying to use `mysql_*` and `mysqli` is a bad comparison, it would be fairer to use `mysqli` and `pdo` for starters, `PDO` offers a wide support of other RDBMS; whereas `mysqli` only supports MySQL. Does that make `mysqli` bad? or less powerful? probably, but it also offers some advatnages of mysqli over `PDO` like the ability to write procedural code. Same thing with the frameworks: CI and CakePHP can be installed in a shared hosting environment without ssh access; whereas Symfony/Zend make such task pretty difficult.

Comment: Well, we're digressing from the Q&A now. Basically, I think if you're going to learn something, anything, do it right first time. Learn the best practise method.